# How can I get Jenkins to run on a different port?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins

I'm having some trouble in trying to change my jenkins port as I was hoping to use port `8080` for a different service. I've tried this so far:

Currently running on `amazon linux`:

Jenkins version: `Jenkins 2.332.1`

I've tried to edit the config file: `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins` to:

```
JENKINS_PORT="7777"
```

After I restart jenkins however, the port does not change:

```
● jenkins.service - Jenkins Continuous Integration Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/jenkins.service.d
           └─override.conf
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2022-04-05 15:52:24 UTC; 1min 33s ago
 Main PID: 1017 (java)
    Tasks: 36
   Memory: 500.6M
   CGroup: /system.slice/jenkins.service
           └─1017 /usr/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar /usr/share/java/jenkins.war --webroot=%C/jenkins/war --httpPort=8080

Apr 05 15:53:38 ip-172-0-2-240.eu-west-1.compute.internal jenkins[1017]: at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
Apr 05 15:53:38 ip-172-0-2-240.eu-west-1.compute.internal jenkins[1017]: at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
```

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the service starting command

```
/usr/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar /usr/share/java/jenkins.war --webroot=%C/jenkins/war --httpPort=8080
```

Edit the service by changing `--httpPort=8080` to desired port then call `daemon-reload` and restart the service

Also, ensure the Security Group is configured for that port

There is a different fix in this link https://cdmana.com/2022/03/202203242138366513.html which suggest editing `JENKINS_PORT` in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service` the calling `service jenkins start`